# How to perform an assessment of an existing network?

Tags: networking, active-directory, iis, windows, troubleshooting

I work as an IT guy for a small company with 2 offices. Currently we are in the process of moving our entire network infrastructure to a different host because we are running everything on extremely outdated Windows servers. The new hosting company will be taking care of most of the moving process, but I was tasked with providing an assessment of our current state.

I am not a network administrator (mostly code and repair PCs in the offices), so I am a little confused on where to begin. I basically need to lay out what each of our domain controllers is responsible for and provide a general overview of each component on our network. I know that we host several apps, and Active Directory server for user management, and probably other things that I'm not aware of yet. I need to piece everything together and provide a solid report to my superiors.

What steps would an experienced network admin take to study existing network infrastructure? What tools would I need?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start by identifying the services that are offered to your users (AD, DHCP, DNS, File, Print, Email, Database, etc.) and identify which servers offer those services. Then identify the LOB (Line Of Business) applications that the users run and how they access and run those LOB's (local installation, database access, email, third party integration applications and services, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know a lot more than you do, to be honest. Even if you had the output from all the tools, and knew where to look for things that can't be automated, what would you do with the information? In your position, I would hire a consultant.

Some tools that I use for a generic Windows infrastructure assessment :

- NMap/ZenMap
- SpiceWorks (includes NMap)
- Microsoft Assessment Tool (MAPS)
- dcdiag and repadmin
- Various Best Practice Analyzers for any MS
  products
- Visio and the discovery add-ons
- Dumps of all network device
  configs
- Dumps of DNS zones, internal and external
- DNS registrar info
- Pictures of the infrastructure

And we haven't even gotten into business applications here.

My approach, above, is server-and-infrastructure-centric, you would consider it bottom-up. You would be well-advised to *also* use @Joeqwerty's approach, which is top-down. Identify the known business services and find out how they are linked to servers, accounts, databases, other servers, etc. This might include hosted services! Your hosted payroll application could depend on an AD LDAP lookup over a VPN, which you would never ever find if you just looked at the servers.

For comparison : My company is a consulting firm that does this, and we take 8 hours for a mid or senior to perform assessments like this. The 8 hours is also just the onsite/data collection portion. We spend more time analyzing and assessing after.

Comment: and 8 hours is pretty optimistic, depending on the environment.  We've spent weeks sorting out "small" networks before, if you include licensing, software compliance, etc.

Comment: If it's a bigger client, we budget more time. The 8 hours is also just the onsite/data collection portion. We spend more time analyzing and assessing after; I wasn't clear about that.

Comment: I don't think that high level of information is required. What if I just wanted to identify the servers we are running in our data center and what they are resposible for (AD, DB, email, etc.) Would I have to get a list of IPs and RDP into them individually, browsing the contents? That's the only thing I can see myself doing right now, but is there a quicker way?

Comment: I respectfully suggest that you're wrong. Do you want this done correctly, or quickly? It's what you *don't* know that will hurt you. You're planning on moving and rebuilding your entire environment. Don't mess this up; it might be a resume-generating event.

Comment: I won't be responsible for anything that relates to migrating components as I'm definitely not experienced enough for that yet. I just need to explain to my boss what server does what in simple terms. Show a list of IPs and go through it saying this server is AD, this one is Exchange, etc. Professional network engineers will be responsible for the actual migration.

Comment: Well then, I've answered your question and given you a handful of tools to get started. If you can't identify an Exchange server by looking in AD, you've got a lot to learn before you'll get this completed.

Comment: If you do run into more specific, bounded questions, please don't hesitate to come back to ServerFault with those new questions. Welcome aboard.